# Как держать окно всегда поверх других окон? (WinAPI, C++)

Tags: c++, winapi

Приложение выводит видеоролик на весь экран, который должен быть всегда поверх всех окон, чтобы его нельзя было свернуть или закрыть другими окнами, пока не выполнятся определённые условия. Для этого каждая итерация в цикле вывода кадров начинается с `SetWindowPos(VideoWindow, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW|SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOMOVE);`, но, к сожалению это не спасает - по `alt+tab` видео можно проигнорировать. Есть такие окна, с которых невозможно перевести фокус на другие приложения - **как это сделать с окном данного видеоролика?**

(ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ ВОПРОСА)

Ответ, который я дал сам, работает через раз...
В связи с комментариями по поводу двух TOPMOST окон добавляю следующий скриншот:
[image: 2xTOPMOST]
Два TOPMOST окна, предположительно со стилями WS_EX_TOPMOST, будут перекрывать друг друга тем, которое из них активно. Такое поведение допустимо.

**Вопрос открыт!**

**КАК сделать всегда в топе Z-порядка видеоролик в cvNamedWindow, так же, как это делает портативный AIMP (который не имеет админских привелегий и не является частью ОС, как тот же диспетчер задач?**

Comment: Теоретически можна ставить в topmost по таймеру. Правда, исходя из ответа, и правда два таких экземпляра "поссорятся":)

Comment: Есть ещё 2-ва "фокуса", клавиатурный, и мышиный, установите заодно и их `SetFocus` и `SetCapture` соответственно. И плюс `SetForegroundWindow`

Comment: А должно ведь быть HWND_TOPMOST а у вас HWND_TOP

Comment: Ещё можно поставить хук на клаву-мышку и прибивать события:)

Comment: Попробуйте ещё WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW в комбинации с WS_POPUP. Тоже получается довольно устойчивый вариант.

Comment: Мне кажется, в данном случае ключевая фраза — "на весь экран". Все игры это делают без проблем. Или я чего не понял?

Answer (score 2):

Как оказалось, это возможно!

```
ActiveWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
if (ActiveWindow != VideoWindow){
    SetWindowPos(ActiveWindow, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOMOVE);
    SetForegroundWindow(VideoWindow);
    SetActiveWindow(VideoWindow);
}
```

Данный вариант работает, но через раз.

***Было найдено следующее решение:***

**Заменить родителя для `cvNamedWindow`, в котором выводится видео, на главное окно программы, которое изначально скрыто (`SW_HIDE`), а при воспроизведении выводится. Главное окно создаётся с `WS_EX_TOPMOST` и `WS_POPUPWINDOW`. В результате поведение окна получается таким же как у диспетчера задач - окно по `alt+tab` появится сверху, но выбранное в нём приложение будет всегда под видео, если это приложение не имеет стиля `WS_EX_TOPMOST`. Если очень нужно прибивать другие окна с `WS_EX_TOPMOST`, можно в параллельном потоке их отлавливать и сравнивать с целевым окном - если не равны по каким-то критериям, то деактивировать или скрывать.**

*Почему-то применение атрибута HWND_TOPMOST не отрабатывало на уже созданном `cvNamedWindow`.*

Comment: Ну если это возможно, запустите _два экземпляра_ и посмотрите, что выйдет.

Answer (score 1):

Это невозможно.

Допустим, это было бы возможно — что если *два* приложения захотели бы одновременно так сделать?

Юмористическое чтение по теме: [How do I create a topmost window that is never covered by other topmost windows?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253/) @ The Old New thing (обязательно прочитайте комментарии).

Comment: Ну хорошо, фиг с ним с ать+табом, но если например открыт проводник, то видео запустится под ним, SetWindowPos не срабатывает. Можно как-нибудь хоть запустить его в топе?

Comment: @Iceman: Странно. А не может ли быть случайно, что вы сначала открываете одно окно, потом закрываете его и открываете другое?

Comment: Вряд ли... Я получаю хендл окна: `HWND VideoWindow = (HWND)cvGetWindowHandle(VideoWindowName);`, затем в начале каждой итерации цикла вывода кадров: `SetWindowPos(VideoWindow, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW|SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOMOVE);
            SetFocus(VideoWindow);` - работает через раз. Например, когда открыт проводник, окно не становится в топе. Когда в топе браузер, когда как - то перебъёт его, то нет